# ==operator overload only on certain occasions

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-overloading

I am making a project that takes in types as templates. The operator== is already overloaded for chars, ints, strings, etc as you know, but if the user decides to pass in a cstring (null terminated character array) I will need to overload the == for that. Can I choose to only overload the operator== when the user uses cstrings, and use the default == when they dont? How would this be accomplished?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Do you mean overload or template specialization?

Comment: The code is very long, and this is a general question anyway. I dont feel it would help. Greatwolf, I mean overload.

Comment: Maybe C++11's 'enable_if' can be used to do it.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to overload `==` for strings here. I'm assuming you're talking about `std::string` which already defines an overloaded `==`

Comment: *"The code is very long, and this is a general question anyway. I dont feel it would help."* - it's a good idea to create minimal code that illustrates the specific issue you're posting here, even if it's not a distillation of your project code.  I for one found your question quite unclear and ambiguously worded (e.g. it's unclear whether "cstring" is a class managing a null terminated character array, or your attempt at describing the latter succinctly, and "takes in types as templates" is very strangely worded).

Comment: @TonyD Noted. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overload `operator==` for C strings, because they are pointers and operators can be overloaded if at least one operand is a class or enum. What you can do is create your own comparator function and use it in your code instead of `==`:

```
template<typename T>
bool my_equal(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return a == b;
}

bool my_equal(const char* a, const char* b) {
    return /* your comparison implementation */;
}
```

Update: you may have to add more overloads to support `std::string` vs `const char*` comparisons, as pointed out by TonyD in comments.

Comment: Sound approach, though for John's *"I also need it to compare cstrings to std::string."* you'd need a couple more overloads....  Cheers.

Comment: Fantastic solution, don't know why I didn't think of this!

Comment: The second "my_equal" solution works for string and cstring comparisons as is. Works great.

Comment: @JohnCalderaio: *"The second "my_equal" solution works for string and cstring comparisons as is."* - not for one against the other - [proof here](http://ideone.com/1CBnGk), but if you don't need that, all's good.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overload the `==` operator on a C-string. I am not completely sure why that should be necessary - the C++ `string` class has defined an implicit conversion from a C-string, and already defines the `==` operator.

Comment: operator== when applied to cstrings compares the pointers for equality, not the contents of the cstring.  That is a HUGE difference--not to mention, why it can't be (safely) used for comparing keys in a map. I also need it to compare cstrings to std::string. The CONTENTS, character by character, NOT the pointer.

Comment: The other answer is far more satisfactory, then.

Comment: @JohnCalderaio *"not to mention, why it can't be (safely) used for comparing keys in a map."* - it can be if you specify a custom comparison, but you're almost always better off making the keys `std::string`s, otherwise if someone inserts a pointer to a string literal it shouldn't be `delete`d, whereas any pointers to stack-based automatic variables need to have their content copied to the stack and be deleted later.  `std::string` will just work in all those situations. *"I also need it to compare cstrings to std::string."* - again, using `std::string` will take care of that....

Answer (score 0):

You can use type traits to dispatch to the correct function. For example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using is_cstring =
    std::integral_constant<bool,
        std::is_same<T, char const*>::value
     || std::is_same<T, char*>::value>;

template<typename T>
class Thingy
{
public:
    bool operator==(Thingy const& rhs) const
    {
        return equal_helper(rhs, is_cstring<T>());
    }
private:
    bool equal_helper(Thingy const& rhs, std::true_type) const
    {
        return strcmp(m_value, rhs.m_value) == 0;
    }

    bool equal_helper(Thingy const& rhs, std::false_type) const
    {
        return m_value == rhs.m_value;
    }

    T m_value;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! You guys have been a great help!