# Comparing == != in templates

Tags: c++, templates, comparison, floating-accuracy

What is the correct way to perform == and != operators in template classes?
Assume this code:

```
template<typename T>
class C {
        T x, y;

        public:
        C(T a, T b) : x(a), y(b) {}

        bool cmp() {
                return x == y;
        }

};

int main()
{
        // OK
        C<int> i(1,2);
        i.cmp();

        // not OK
        C<double> d(1.0, 2.0);
        d.cmp();

        return 0;
}
```

If you build it with g++ -Wfloat-equal, you'll get

> warning: comparing floating point with == or != is unsafe
>   [-Wfloat-equal]

because you can't simply compare float variables.

---

### Update

I've solved the problem using type_traits and enable_if like this (thanks @Andrew and @OMGtechy):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename IntegralType>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<IntegralType>::value, bool>::type
equal(const IntegralType& a, const IntegralType& b) {
        return a == b;
}

template <typename FloatingType>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<FloatingType>::value, bool>::type
equal(const FloatingType& a, const FloatingType& b) {
        return std::fabs(a-b) < std::numeric_limits<FloatingType>::epsilon();
}

template<typename T>
class C {
    T x, y;

    public:
    C(T a, T b) : x(a), y(b) {}

    bool cmp() {
        return equal(x, y);
    }

};

int main()
{
    // OK
    C<int> i(1,2);
    cout << i.cmp() << endl;

    // not OK
    C<double> d(1.0, 1.0);
    cout << d.cmp() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are concerned about the type not having an appropriate `operator==`, consider added a argument to the template that is the comparator to be used (and then have the default be `std::equal_to`)

Comment: This has a lot to do with comparing floating point values, but virtually nothing to do with templates.

Comment: What is correct depends on the use case. What do you want to happen for floating point here? For some cases, `==` is perfectly fine with floating point. For others, checking for near values is correct.

Comment: @Biffen Actually, I think it's a good question. How to implement this template so it handles all types including floating point values?

Comment: @JosephMansfield The code given handles all types already.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Oh, OK then. But I didn't mean to say it was a bad question.

Comment: @interjay I'm aware of that, but the asker wants to know how you would implement a template that is capable of handling the fact that some people might want a "safer" form of comparison for floating point values. There are a couple of approaches to this.

Comment: There was a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27220464/3959454) recently.

Comment: "you can't simply compare float variables" - yes you can. You just can't rely on mathematically equivalent calculations giving exactly equal results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question seems to be asking two things:

1. How can I do floating point comparisons without using operator==, and
2. how can I modify the behaviour of a template depending on the type passed to it.

One answer to the second question is to use type traits. The code below demonstrates this for your situation, providing a comparison_traits for general types (using ==) and a specialisation for doubles, using a tolerance (which answers the first question, too).

```
#include <cmath>

template <typename T> struct comparison_traits {
  bool equal(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return a == b;
  }

  // etc.
};

template<> struct comparison_traits<double> {
  bool equal(const double& a, const double& b) {
    return fabs(a - b) < 1e-15; // or whatever...
  }
};

template <typename T>
class C {
  T x, y;

  public:
    C(const T& a, const T& b) : x(a), y(b) {}

    bool cmp() {
      return comparison_traits<T>::equal(x, y);
    }
};

int main() {
  // OK
  C<int> i(1, 2);
  i.cmp();

  // Now OK too...
  C<double> d(1.0, 2.0);
  d.cmp();

  return 0;
}
```

Other options include:

- Providing a template parameter that allows you to specify a comparison function, defaulting to std::equal_to
- Specialising your template for double, so that you can write a different implementation of cmp()

Comment: You could use type traits to do it for all floating point types rather than specialising for double and float seperately

Comment: True. I wanted to stick fairly close to the example in the question, though. Also, it doesn't hurt to leave some things as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends how it will be used. Comparing floats properly depends on the context.

I would recommend what @Niall says: add a comparator template parameter, defaulting to `std::equal_to`. This will allow callers to control how values are compared. See for example the docs on `std::sort` to see how a comparator parameter is used. The downside to this is that it's the caller's responsibility to account for comparing `float`s. If they forget, then they'll get the compiler warning you see.

Another option is template class specialization. Make a specialization for your class to deal specifically with `float` or `double` types, and compare them differently using whatever logic you prefer. Probably not the best solution though. The benefit to this is that callers no longer need to remember to specify a comparator.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask why you get this warning:

here some example:

```
double a,b;
a=10.0/13.0;
b = a/3;
b*=3;

std::cout<<"a="<<a<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"b="<<b<<std::endl;
if(a!=b){
    std::cout<<"NOT  equal!!"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"a-b="<<a-b<<std::endl;
}
else
    std::cout<<"equal"<<std::endl;
```

if you'll do the math a and b are clearly equal.
but this is the output I've got:

```
a=0.769231
b=0.769231
NOT  equal!!
a-b=-1.11022e-016
```

because it is not so accurate, a proper comparison for double should define some tolerancy:

for example(tolerancy may change according needs):

```
int compare(double a, double b)
{
    double tolerancy = 0.000001;
    if (abs(a-b) < tolerancy) return 0;
    else if (a>b) return 1;
    else /*if (a<b)*/ return -1;
}
```

and if I use this compare i get:

```
a=0.769231
b=0.769231
equal
```